# Show JSON data in multi select box

Tags: angularjs, json, list, controller, angularjs-ng-options

I got some problem as I am new in Angular. I tried to show one of the JSON key value in multi select box options but failed to load.

I had gone through the example over here and I am doing same function by clicking button.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TdueXL8BQTi8DOodnD5q?p=preview

*So the **controller** part :-*

```
$scope.master = {};

              $scope.addValue = function(ff) {
                 $scope.master = angular.copy(ff);
                  $http.post("url", $scope.master).success(function(data) { 
                        $scope.use= data;
                       console.log("Successful");

                  },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                       console.log("something went wrong");
                  });
                     console.log($scope.master);
                };
```

So my `master={}` is binding user input in JSON value ie; `{"Name":"","Motor":"","Company":""}` . I want to show `Name` only, on repeat.

***View*** is :-

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="reg_select_multiple" class="form-control">
 <option ng-repeat="x in master" value="{{x.name}}"></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: `$scope.master` is an object, not a collection so you can't use `ng-repeat` in the manner you are attempting. Did you mean to do `ng-repeat="(key, value) in master"`?

Comment: @Lex Yes , I need to do show the `(key(ie; master.Name),value)` on button click as same that  had shown in that plnkr example.

Comment: And even if I am using `<ul> <li ng-repeat="question in master.Name">{{question}}</li></ul>`  I am getting this error '[ngRepeat:dupes]'. And also my single string gets divided. @Lex

Comment: Again, `ng-repeat` works on collections. It appears that `master.Name` is a string, not a collection.

Comment: @Lex So any work around ? I used `ng-repeat="question in master.Name track by $index"` to solve ` [ngRepeat:dupes]`

Comment: What is the data that is returned from your `$http.post`? Does that contain the collection of items you're trying to show in your `<select>`?

Comment: @Lex No , Just an ID.

Comment: I have no idea then. Nothing in your question seems to be something containing a collection.